# Rails - Show message just one time to User

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to display to User a message just once. (like a tutorial).

Do you know if there is a GEM who manage that ? Or what the best way to do so ?

I think of store the IP in database. But I'm afraid that is going to slow down my website.

The message is warning about the utilization of Cookie (we have to do that in France...)

Comment: You want to show a message to a *user*, so why not create a boolean column in database instead of messing up with IP?

Comment: By User I mean all users of my website :/ Excuse-me for this confusion

Comment: if it's a per user toggle, then there's no other way to persist that data other than saving it somewhere (db/redis).  using session and cookies are dependent on the browser so you can't use that.  just like Arslan said, just add another column in your db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that is a common scenario that occurs many times in web development. I'd go with two options here:

### Cookies persistence:

You may like to store the result in Cookies if a anyone visiting your site has seen the notification. The only disadvantage to this problem is that when the user clears the cookies, he would see the notification again. And that's perfectly fine. So many sites use cookies to store temporary information, and that information gets removed whenever the user clears the cache/cookies.

### IP filtering:

You may want to store the IPs in the database who have visited your site and seen the notification. But when a new comes form a particular IP, you then need to check it against all the IPs stored in the database, if found, don't show any notification - otherwise show.

I'd personally go with **Cookies Persistence** option, instead of utilizing my database for this purpose. And storing all the IPs in the database, and searching a new IP among the already stored ones does have a slight performance hint, so be aware.

> Do you know if there is a GEM who manage that ? Or what the best way to do so ?

Personally, I haven't come across any gem like that. And the best way: It is up to you. Do what you think will solve your problem best.

Comment: I use the Cookie Way :) Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Storing something in database just to use it one time is useless in my opinion. I don't know any gem but I did similar thing one time. After user registration I added param to redirect url, and a method that checks if param exist. If true - display message/tutorial. Param was added only after register so after login to page it message was not displayed again. It is not perfect but simple and working solution.

Comment: As I said in another comment, I'd like to print this message to any user even if he's not registred ! Excuse me for this confusion...